# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot uninstall 3rd party via GNOME-Softare

Tags: software-center, 16.04

So I know there's a bunch of post about installing 3rd party software via GNOME-Software (aka "Ubuntu Softare") but it looks like that may have been resolved with an update.  HOWEVER, now that I've installed a 3rd party app (google-musicmanager-beta_current_amd64"), I can't seem to find it under "Installed" software to remove it... Using APT, I get "google-musicmanager-beta/now 1.0.243.1116-r0 amd64 [installed,local]" so Ubuntu recognizes it as installed, but not as far as GNOME-Software can tell.  Is anyone aware of a submitted bug on this or am I just missing something?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was easy.... Solved via reboot.  What is this, Windows? :)